# django problem using syncdb

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem when trying to run syncdb. My models:

```
class TeachSubject(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    taught_class  = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.date.today().year)
    semester = models.IntegerField()

    #class Meta:
        #db_table = 'subject_teachers'
```

another file:

```
from customUsers.models import TeachSubject

class SubjectPeriod(models.Model):
    days = ((1, 'Mon'),
            (2, 'Tues'),
            (3, 'Wed'),
            (4,'Thurs'),
            (5,'Friday'))
    tsc = models.ForeignKey(TeachSubject)
    day = models.IntegerField(choices = days)
    period = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subject_period'
        unique_together = ('day', 'period', 'tsc')
```

Tried running syncdb, the table `subject_period` is created alright. The thing is, after checking the database itself, strangely no foreign key constraint is created for the line `tsc = models.ForeignKey(TeachSubject)`.

Anyone can shed some light? Using django 1.2.4 (ps. I spent some time checking before posting here. So I beg your forgiveness if it was a careless mistake)

**EDIT**:

ok I deleted the tables and retried creating the tables using south instead. Works fine now, but it would be still good to know what went wrong with the former method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your two models are from different apps.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) says:

To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly specify a model with the full application label. For example, if the Manufacturer model above is defined in another application called production, you'd need to use:

so your foreignkeyfield will look like:

```
tsc = models.ForeignKey('customUsers.TeachSubject')
```

This also means you don't have to import the models from the other application (also solving problems of circular imports.

It seems strange that you dont get an error - just nothing at all - but try that, it might just work.

Comment: I must have missed this in the docs. Anyway, have fixed the issue using south. thanks for enlightening anyway